# OnClick issue in ListView android

Tags: android, listview

I have a view element in the ListView Item and a Custom Adapter class. When clicking on the first element's view then it changes the last elements data rather than changing the one which is clicked.

The data is coming from firebase database. There is no issue in the Data. The only problem is the the change happens at some other element of listview.

Any solutions to these?

Comment: let me know how you are handling it in your code

Comment: show us your adapter code please..

Comment: What are you using for that, `onChildChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

The way I manage item clicks is like this.

In the view, I set the adapter and the click listener to the item:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(thisView.getContext(), R.layout.list_view, listItems));
listView.setOnItemClickListener(onClickItemListView());
```

In the onclick method:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onClickItemListView()
{
    return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Item i = listItems.get(position);
            // do what you need to do with the item clicked
        }
    };
}
```

Where `listItems` is any global List variable of your whole data to be displayed in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

so i don't understand the context but this should work

```
Item i = listItems.get(position);
```

`if (i == yourParameterIndex){`

`//do your staff here`

`}`